# add query parameter of some url to every url of the site in vue js project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

If there is a query parameter in some url, for example, some.url?inviteId=123. Then user jump to any other link of the same site, the parameter of invitedId attaches to the other url link. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood. But you can access the inviteId with Vue-router in any component by doing:

`this.$route.query;`

The on `created` life hook or on a `watch` you can do something like:

`this.$router.push({ path: 'new-path', query: this.$route.query });`

Vue Router Docs: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/

Comment: The new-path must be any other url in the project. How to know the value of the 'new-path'?

Comment: You'll need to set it in your routes (usually in a dedicated file, as shown on VueRouter)


`const routes = [`
`  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },`
`  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }`
`]`

Then you will be free to them in any component

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to get url from browser http and use it axios. Hope this is helpful

```
mounted(){            
       
        axios.get(this.url)
                .then(response => { this.list = response.data });
    },         
    data:
    {          
        list :'',          
        url:'/progress/getmonthlyreportdata/?'+ window.location.search.substring(1)
    },
```